# Preciso apagar uma pasta

Tags: funções

Olá, usando o visual studio, eu gostaria de pagar a seguinte pasta : C:\Users\leoxs\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\browser

Só que este programa vai ser utilizado por outras pessoas, e elas também precisam excluir está mesma pasta, só que o "inicio" (C:\Users\leoxs) vai ser diferente, (AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\browser) esse destino sempre é fixo

Como eu faço para excluir esta pasta?

Oque eu tentei e não deu certo:
`Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click`
`File.Delete("C:\Users\leoxs\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\browser")`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, o Windows usa [variáveis de ambiente](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) que apontam para vários diretórios dentro do sistema.

No seu caso, você pode usar este caminho:

```
File.Delete("%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\browser")
```

Você não deu mais detalhes, então não sei se isso vai resolver. Mas o caminho que você procura é esse mesmo `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local`. Você pode testar copiando e colando a string anterior no Windows Explorer.